# creating tabular environment with left aligned columns

Tags: tables

Hi any suggestions to follow to reproduce this table. there is a caption of table

[image]

```
  \begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Estimated posterior moments}
 \begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
   \toprule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Gold}} \\   
    \cmidrule(r){1-6}
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Parameter}} & \textit{Posterior mean}& 
      \textit{Standard error} & \textit{90\% credible interval}\\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{ c }}   &  0.508 & 0.258    & [0.083, 0.933]   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{\beta}} &  2.960 & 0.224    & [2.622, 3.302]  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{b}}     &  0.025 & 0.04     & [0.019, 0.031]   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{\alpha}}&  0.966 & 0.010    & [0.947, 0.981]   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{\theta}}&  0.024 & 0.006    & [0.016, 0.035]  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{\sigma}}&  0.004 &  0.001   & [0.003, 0.006]  &      &    \\

   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \label{tab5}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: `tabular` environment with 8 left aligned columns, rules from the `booktabs` package for the horizontal lines.

Comment: Apart from that, please show what you tried so far, preferrably with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also, please clarify your question: What part(s)  of the table are problematic for you to recreate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide MWE (minimal working example), a compilable small document which reproduce at least part of your table and show your problem. What is the problem is not very clear ... see if my guessing was correct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Estimated posterior moments}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{>{$}l<{$} cc r@{,\ }l}}
    \toprule
\thead[lb]{Parameter} & \thead[lb]{Posterior\\ mean} & \thead[lb]{Standard\\ error} 
                     & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\thead[lb]{90\% credible\\ interval}}   
    & \thead[lb]{Parameter} & \thead[lb]{Posterior\\ mean} & \thead[lb]{Standard\\ error}
                          & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\thead[lb]{90\% credible\\ interval}}   \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-5}   \cmidrule(l){6-10}
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Gold}} 
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Silver}}            \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-5}   \cmidrule(l){6-10}
c       &  0.508 & 0.258    & (0.083 & 0.933)    
        & c      & 0.560    & 0.408  &(-0.111 & 1.232)      \\
\beta   &  2.960 & 0.224    & (2.622 & 3.302)    
        & \beta  & 3.989    & 0.142  & (3.750 & 4.224)      \\
b       &  0.025 & 0.04     & (0.019 & 0.031)  
        & b      & 0.020    & 0.002  & (0.016 & 0.024)      \\
\alpha  &  0.966 & 0.010    & (0.947 & 0.981)   
        & \alpha & 0.951    & 0.012  & (0.928 & 0.965)      \\
\theta  &  0.024 & 0.006    & (0.016 & 0.035)   
        & \theta & 0.022    & 0.005  & (0.015 & 0.031)      \\
\sigma  &  0.004 & 0.001    & (0.003 & 0.006)   
        & \sigma & 0.003    & 0.001  & (0.002 & 0.004)      \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Copper}} 
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Platinum}}          \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-5}   \cmidrule(l){6-10}
c       &  0.292 & 0.337    &(-0.253 & 0.848)   
        & c      & 0.795    & 0.370  & (0.186 & 0.004)      \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \label{tab5}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the main differences between your code fragment and my MWE is different definition of columns types, use of `\thead` commands from the `makcell` packages for column headers and use two columns for "credible" interval.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help,  i really appreciate, it's professional

Comment: @haithem, if you like the answer, you can vote for it, or if it solves your problem, you can accept it :-)

Comment: could we reduce the size of the numbers to the same size as for the labels of columns?

Comment: @haithem, yes, you could. Set the same font size for the table and for the `\thead`. BTW, so far I had impression, that my answer is not useful for you since you not accept it :-)

Comment: it was useful to me, You have been most helpful several times,

Comment: @haithem, you are velcome. For font size: (i) in preamble wrie `\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}` , (ii) in table environment, after `\begin{table}` write `\small` . After then whole table (except caption, which font size is defined by document class or caption settings) will have the same font size.